# Struct size in C++ & conversion to C#

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, arduino, type-conversion

I'm having an issue working from Arduino to Unity; essentially I'm building a payload struct in C++ (Arduino) and sending it to a PC using the following serial protocol:

1 byte - header

1 byte - payload size

X bytes - payload

1 byte - checksum (LRC)

The payload looks like so:

```
struct SamplePayload {
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
    double D;
} payload;
```

when I sizeof(payload) I get 16 bytes, when I believe a double is an 8 byte data type; if I add another double the struct is 20 bytes and so on. Am I misunderstanding something? This is causing issues as this is then converted to a byte data stream and cast as a struct on receipt in C#, and I'm not sure what the equivalent datatype would be (casting as a double gives wrong values). The serial protocol in Unity also relies on the correct payload size to read out the stream.

It is probably a straightforward answer but I couldn't find it anywhere, many thanks!

Comment: Just a random idea but wouldn't working with byte arrays just fix alle the issues you have? Maybe I missunderstood the problem tho

Comment: `double` on many Arduino platforms is [4 bytes](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/).

Comment: Depends which arduino you have - see https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/

Comment: Beware that floating point number types aren't strictly standardized. The most common format is IEEE 754 though implementations are free to use something else. The memory representation may not be compatible between platforms.

Comment: Beware of padding (due to alignment requirements) between members and at the end of the struct.

Comment: Can you say the range (minimum and maximum) and resolution of the numbers you want to send as A, B, C, and D? That information would make it easier for people to suggest a solution that doesn't use double type values.  Thanks, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not numerically sensitive, you could use the following approach:

Instead of using doubles within your struct (which aren't strictly standardized, as mentioned in the comments), you could use two `int32_t`, `a` and `b` for representing a significant and an exponent such that
*a*2^b = original_double*

So your struct will look something like this:

```
    struct SamplePayload {
    int32_t A_sig;
    int32_t A_exp;
    //B,C...
} payload;
```

Then on the receiving side, you will only have to multiply according to the formula above to get the original double.

C provides you with a neat function, **`frexp`**, to ease things up.
But since we store both `a` and `b` as integers, we need to modify the results a bit in order to get high precision.

Specifically, since `a` is guaranteed to be between 0.5 and 1, you need to multiply `a` by 2^30, and subtract 30 from `b` in order not to overflow.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* frexp */
#include <stdint.h>

int main ()
{
  double param, result;
  int32_t a,b;

  param = +235.0123123;
  result = frexp (param , &b);
  a=(result*(1<<30)) /*2^30*/; b-=30;
  printf ("%f = %d * 2^%d\n", param, a, b); //235.012312 = 985713081 * 2^-22                                                                                                                 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm not getting the same results as you unfortunately; my code is as follows:  
  
  
    int setExponent(double val, int32_t *sig, int32_t *xp){  
      double result;  
      int16_t b;  
      result = frexp (val, &b);  
      *sig = (result*(2^30));  
      *xp = b-30;  
      return 0;  
    }  
  
As `frexp()` only accepts `int16_t` in my compiler